# Navigation arrows for Stock Tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm trying to implement navigation arrows for stock tools using `Highcharts/Highstock` with the React wrapper. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/bernardo0marques/v4sytzg6/) is a working example for a non React application.

My attempt with React is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stock-tools-demo-ji8ow). I couldn't find any documentation about those arrows. Comparing the codes, the only diference is that *chart options* are wrapped on a `container` on the first example, but I couldn't replicate that on React.

Also, I can't find anything on [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/stockTools) related to stock tools positioning on chart (bottom/top/right/left) or how to handle the minimize arrow for it. Is the only solution via CSS?

Any tips on how to implement that?

---

## Update

I Have added

```js
<HighchartsReact
  ...
  containerProps={{ className: "chart" }}
/>
```

to my [updated](https://codesandbox.io/s/stock-tools-demo-v2-mqzmp) example, and also updated dependencies. Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used Highcharts v7.0.3, since v7.1.3 the problem with arrow icons seems to be resolved. Additionally, add `chart` class name to get the proper height for stock tools.

```
<HighchartsReact
  ...
  containerProps={{ className: "chart" }}
/>
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/pie-chart-64hmo

Comment: I'm running: highcharts: 8.0.0 and highcharts-react-official: 3.0.0 on my local application. Adding the `containerProps={{ className: "chart" }}` made the navigation arrows appear but I can't interact with them. CodeSandBox application seems to work but the arrows icons don't show.

Comment: Hi @Bernardo Marques, Could you reproduce that in the online code editor or send me a package with your project?

Comment: I'm running a logic for double click on `Legend Click Event` that was breaking single click for that event (That I was able to handle as a condition inside double click). But as far as I was concerned this double click event wouldn't affect other click events.

Comment: I have just noticed that adding `containerProps={{ className: "chart" }}` hides the legend. Is that expected?

Comment: @Bernardo Marques - The legend should work correctly: https://codesandbox.io/s/pie-chart-jc8ir